# English grammer-Participle

Tags: usage, participles

I would  be pleased if someone could explain to me the participle in this sentence :

> James has made a breakthrough in his math this year, doing excellent work in comparison with last year

Comment: [Please note: the verb explain needs to be used like this: if someone could explain **to me** the participle, etc.]

Answer (score 0):

> *James has made a breakthrough in his math this year,* [*doing excellent*
> *work in comparison with last year*].

The bracketed element is a gerund-participial (non-finite) clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct.

Supplements are not modifiers, but loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Although supplements are not syntactically dependent on a head, they are semantically related to an 'anchor' (sometimes called a 'host'). In your example, the anchor is the subject of the clause which the supplement follows, i.e. "James".

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your comment but can you give an explanation simply.

Comment: You mean the bracketed element functions as an adverb?

Comment: @ibrahimsahingil Is it just the grammar that you are asking about?

Comment: @ibrahimsahingil No; it doesn't modify anything, so I wouldn't call it an adverbial. It's an extra piece of optional information about the subject James", added on at the end of the sentence.

Comment: yes, and can you explain it simply?

Comment: is it this just shortened                                                                                                   James has made a breakthrough in his math this year ,and James did excellent work in comparison with last year.

Comment: @ibrahimsahingil Essentially, yes.